# Is there flavor in the white of an egg?

Tags: job

Job 6:6
English Standard Version:

> Can that which is tasteless be eaten without salt, or is there any taste in the juice of the mallow?

Berean Study Bible:

> Is tasteless food eaten without salt, or is there flavor in the white of an egg?

Which translation is better?

Comment: Why do ESV & BSB translate רִיר Rir ("Saliva") as Juice & White?

Comment: That's the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there flavor in the white of an egg?

The two words in question here are "juice/white" and "mallow/egg". Let's take one at a time.

**Juice or white?**
רִיר (riyr [Strong's H7388](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/7388.htm))
spittle, white of an egg
From  [ruwr](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/7325.htm); saliva; by resemblance, broth -- spittle, white (of an egg).

**Mallow or egg?**
חַלָּמוּת (challamuth [Strong's H2495](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/2495.htm))
egg
From  [chalam](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/2492.htm)  (in the sense of insipidity); probably purslain -- egg.

Let's see what [Barnes' Notes on the Bible](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/barnes/job/6.htm) has to say on this:

> Or is there any taste in the white of an egg? - Critics and commentators have been greatly divided about the meaning of this. The Septuagint renders it, εἰ δέ καί ἐστί γεῦμα ἐν ῥήμασι κενοῖς ei de kai esti geuma en rēmasi kenois; is there any taste in vain words? Jerome (Vulgate), "can anyone taste that which being tasted produces death?" The Targums render it substantially as it is in our version. The Hebrew word rendered "white" (ריר rı̂yr) means properly spittle;  [1 Samuel 21:13](https://biblehub.com/1_samuel/21-13.htm). If applied to an egg, it means the white of it, as resembling spittle. The word rendered "egg" (חלמוּת challâmûth) occurs nowhere else in the Scriptures. If it be regarded as derived from חלם châlam, to sleep, or dream, it may denote somnolency or dreams, and then fatuity, folly, or a foolish speech, as resembling dreams; and many have supposed that Job meant to characterize the speech of Eliphaz as of this description.
>
> The word may mean, as it does in Syriac, a species of herb, the "purslain" (Gesenius), proverbial for its insipidity among the Arabs, Greeks, and Romans, but which was used as a salad; and the whole phrase here may denote purslain-broth, and hence, an insipid discourse. This is the interpretation of Gesenius. But the more common and more probable explanation is that of our common version, denoting the white of an egg. But what is the point of the remark as Job uses it? That it is a proverbial expression, is apparent; but in what way Job meant to apply it, is not so clear. The Jews say that he meant to apply it to the speech of Eliphaz as being insipid and dull, without anything to penetrate the heart or to enliven the fancy; a speech as disagreeable to the mind as the white of an egg was insipid to the taste. Rosenmuller supposes that he refers to his afflictions as being as unpleasant to bear as the white of an egg was to the taste. It seems to me that the sense of all the proverbs used here is about the same, and that they mean, "there is a reason for everything which occurs. The ass brays and the ox lows only when destitute of food. That which is insipid is unpleasant, and the white of an egg is loathsome. So with my afflictions. They produce loathing and disgust, My very food  [Job 6:7](https://biblehub.com/job/6-7.htm)  is disagreeable, and everything seems tasteless as the most insipid food would. Hence the language which I have used - language spoken not without reason, and expressive of this state of the soul."

Also, the topic "[Marshmallow](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200002916)" in the *Insight on the Scriptures* notes:

> A perennial plant that is closely related to the hollyhock. The woody stems of the marshmallow (*Althaea officinalis*) measure up to 1.8 m (6 ft) in height. The plant’s large, wide leaves are notched and terminate in a sharp point. Both the stems and the leaves are covered with soft downy hair. The pale-pink, five-petal flowers are about 5 cm (2 in.) across. In times of famine, the marshmallow’s white carrotlike root has been used for food. The sole Scriptural reference to the marshmallow alludes to its tastelessness.​—[Job 6:6](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002916/0/0).
>
> The Hebrew term  *chal·la·muthʹ,*  found only at  [Job 6:6](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002916/1/0), has been variously rendered “egg” (*AS, KJ*), “purslain” (*AT*), and, as defined in a Hebrew and Aramaic lexicon by L. Koehler and W. Baumgartner, “marsh-mallow” (*Lexicon in Veteris Testamenti Libros,*  Leiden, 1958, p. 304).

So it seems that the ESV has taken a more literal translation and the BSB is an interpretive translation. Here is where the approach to Bible translation comes in. The ESV is accurate but would most readers know what mallow is? Whereas, the BSB is trying to convey the thought of the narrative while being more easily understood by the reader.